# Removing newlines in ruby JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

So, I am serialising an object in Ruby on Rails into JSON format, using to_json. The output produced is:

```
'{"description":"---\n- Nulla adipisci quia consequuntur nam ab et. Eius enim ad aut. Asperiores recusandae\n  labore exercitationem.\n    quos provident.\n","id":295,"name":"Animi enim dolorem soluta eligendi inventore quia distinctio magni.","privacy":0,"updated_at":"2012-11-18T22:24:17Z","user_id":1}'
```

This needs to be parsed by JSON.parse to deserialise the object in client-side javascript. At the moment, this is failing because of the newline characters `\n` in the "description" value. I've tried to encode the characters appropriately using `gsub("\n","\\n")` and other permutations, but I can't seem to find a string or regular expression that will correctly match the newlines (and only the newlines). I have tried `/\n/`, `'\n'`, `"\n"`, `"\\n"` (this matches everywhere on the string, for some reason), `/\\n/` and so on, but haven't been able to find anything. Any ideas what I am missing?

**Update**: here's the code (javascript, but with embedded ruby) I'm trying to use to populate the javascript object (it's in an ERB view, hence the angle brackets):

```
var object = JSON.parse('<%= raw @object.to_json %>');
```

`to_json` is not overridden in my object code, just the standard rails method.

Comment: That example isn't valid JSON and isn't the output of a `to_json` method. Please show a better example along with code you're using to generate the string.

Comment: What's not valid about it? I copied and pasted directly from my IDE, but I did remove some extra fields, so that might be the problem.

Comment: Try assigning it to a string in IRB. The output of JSON serializing is a string, so the example, if it's correct, should be directly assignable, or try parsing it back into a Ruby object from the JSON string. `"{"description":"` quotes `'{'` and leaves `description` bare, which is a syntax error.

Comment: My mistake: I have changed the outer double quotes to single quotes. Any chance that you could help me with my question?

Comment: So that code is a string of javascript, in an ERB view, and that is Ruby code within the angle brackets?

Comment: yes: I have further edited the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON includes a YAML string, so don't waste time trying to remove the line feeds, or you'll make things worse, or at least cause yourself to do too much work.

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

json = '{"description":"---\n- Nulla adipisci quia consequuntur nam ab et. Eius enim ad aut. Asperiores recusandae\n  labore exercitationem.\n    quos provident.\n","id":295,"name":"Animi enim dolorem soluta eligendi inventore quia distinctio magni.","privacy":0,"updated_at":"2012-11-18T22:24:17Z","user_id":1}'

hash = JSON[json]
puts YAML.load(hash['description'])
```

Outputs:

```
Nulla adipisci quia consequuntur nam ab et. Eius enim ad aut. Asperiores recusandae labore exercitationem. quos provident.
```

The JSON, after decoding back into a Ruby hash, looks like:

```
{"description"=>
  "---\n- Nulla adipisci quia consequuntur nam ab et. Eius enim ad aut. Asperiores recusandae\n  labore exercitationem.\n    quos provident.\n",
 "id"=>295,
 "name"=>"Animi enim dolorem soluta eligendi inventore quia distinctio magni.",
 "privacy"=>0,
 "updated_at"=>"2012-11-18T22:24:17Z",
 "user_id"=>1}
```

To turn it back into a true JSON string, with `description` not encoded as YAML, use:

```
hash['description'] = YAML.load(hash['description']).shift
puts hash.to_json
```

Which now looks like:

```
{"description":"Nulla adipisci quia consequuntur nam ab et. Eius enim ad aut. Asperiores recusandae labore exercitationem. quos provident.","id":295,"name":"Animi enim dolorem soluta eligendi inventore quia distinctio magni.","privacy":0,"updated_at":"2012-11-18T22:24:17Z","user_id":1}
```

Comment: Yes, I did wonder why a YAML start marker was in there, but there was quite a bit of confusion going on :) @Rory, you should accept this answer.

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea what that `---` is doing there: I assume that's what you're talking about with the YAML string. Is the `---` actually going to cause a problem with parsing for JSON? I assumed that it would be interpreted as part of the "description" string. Certainly, manually removing newlines from my JSON string allowed JSON.parse to deserialise it. At the moment, I'm mainly curious as to why the hell a simple regex is failing to work in my code...

Comment: `---` is the document marker in YAML. That was my first clue that field was YAML.

Answer (score 1):

```
j = %Q!{"description":"---\n- Nulla adipisci quia consequuntur nam ab et. Eius enim ad aut. Asperiores recusandae\n  labore exercitationem.\n    quos provident.\n","id":295,"name":"Animi enim dolorem soluta eligendi inventore quia distinctio magni.","privacy":0,"updated_at":"2012-11-18T22:24:17Z","user_id":1}!
j.gsub! /\n/, '\\n'
JSON.parse j
# => {"description"=>"---\n- Nulla adipisci quia consequuntur nam ab et. Eius enim ad aut. Asperiores recusandae\n  labore exercitationem.\n    quos provident.\n", "id"=>295, "name"=>"Animi enim dolorem soluta eligendi inventore quia distinctio magni.", "privacy"=>0, "updated_at"=>"2012-11-18T22:24:17Z", "user_id"=>1}
```

Make your life easy, use single quotes around escaped characters when you need to manipulate them.

---

After the update…

```
var object = JSON.parse('<%= raw @object.to_json.gsub(/\n/, %q!\\n!) %>');
```

Comment: I have tried `gsub(/\n/,<some string to substitute>)` (as I mentioned above): but for some reason it doesn't actually match the newlines in my string. I'm parsing the output directly, so using `gsub` as opposed to !gsub shouldn't make any difference, AFAIK.

Comment: Have you tried copy and pasting my code into an IRB session and seeing if it works?

Comment: Not yet, will double-check when I get the chance. I'm pretty confused as to what's going on here, as your answer *should* work, but isn't for my code. I'm obviously missing something, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: You haven't supplied any code, just a string with some JSON in, so it's difficult for anyone to tell you what you've done wrong. `gsub!` makes a difference because you may be parsing an unchanged string if you used `gsub` and didn't assign the result to a new variable (or overwrite the old one). The single quotes obviously make a difference… you basically need to show us what _you_ did if you want an explanation.

Comment: thanks, but that still doesn't work. Other regexes eg `/n/` seem to work fine and match what I'd expect, so I have no idea why I can't seem to match newlines.

Comment: @RoryB Ok, then you need to test it at different points in the response cycle to check that what you're working on is what you expect, as the above code works in IRB. Consider using [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) to jump into the code and inspect the object / try out a few things, and/or `warn` to output to the terminal from within the controller and the view. You might also be better doing the conversion within the controller and assigning that to a variable, to make sure nothing else withing the view (`raw` etc) is affecting the output.